# SIGPIPE 13 with ASyncUDPsocket

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an NTP framework in my App and it makes use of ASyncUDPsocket, however this framework makes the App break after coming back from the background after a while.

NetworkClock source: https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/issues/attachmentText?id=8&aid=6136447331175276042&name=NetworkClock.m&token=ky6UNYWjqChe2rQkEv1a_VSDpqk%3A1372342874389

AsyncUdpSocket source: http://pastebin.com/tuKqpnqZ

Breakpoints are:

```
[self doSend:[self socketForPacket:theCurrentSend]];
```

And:

```
result = sendto(theNativeSocket, buf, (size_t)bufSize, 0, dst, (socklen_t)dstSize);
```

I tried suggestions here:
https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/issues/detail?id=8
But so far the app stills crashes with a `iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:nl.app[0x8f48]' exited abnormally with signal 13: Broken pipe: 13` error.
How can I prevent this?